# Similarity between two sets of lat/long points

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, distance, sql-server-spatial, similarity

I am trying to measure the similarity between two trajectories (two sets of lat/long points) which are the outputs from two APIs. I am trying to measure the difference between the routes given by these two APIs and give an estimate of how much percentage of routes match. I have seen about [Frechet Distance](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance) and [Hausdorff Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html) but couldn't understand the details. My understanding is Frechet Distance gives even better results than Hausdorff Distance and my idea is to take the two polylines (outputs from two APIs) and take their Frechet Distance. But how can I get the percentage of match between these two routes. Does 
***densifyFrac*** parameter in these methods can give any such information. Or are there any better approaches for this problem.